# Conditional operator in object creation

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have this code :

```
private MyClass CreateObject(MyOtherClass myOtherClass)
{
    return new MyClass
    {
        Name = myOtherClass.Name,
        ValidationDate = (DateTime)myOtherClass.ValidationDate  //ValidationDate is nullable
    };
}
```

If I do this, I have a compilation error :

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is 
>   no implicit conversion between `'<null>'` and `'System.DateTime'`

```
private MyClass CreateObject(MyOtherClass myOtherClass)
{
    return new MyClass
    {
        Name = myOtherClass.Name,
        ValidationDate = (myOtherClass.VALIDATION_DATE == null) ? null : DateTime.Now  //ValidationDate is nullable
    };
}
```

If I do this, no problem :

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
if (myClass.ValidationDate == null)
    myClass.ValidationDate = null;
```

The question is why ?  and Solustion ? :)

Comment: What is the type of `MyClass.ValidationDate` and `MyOtherClass.ValidationDate` ?

Comment: When you say "if I do this, no problem". I beg to differ, you don't do anything there. You're setting null to a value that was already null.

Comment: Nitpic - The null coalescing operator is `??`. You are talking about the conditional operator `?:`.

Comment: @Oded I pointed this out in my answer 1 minute after yours; +1 for editing the title.

Comment: @Bridge - You can always make a suggested edit yourself, you know.

Comment: @Oded Can't wait until I gain the priviledge of editing myself; I often suggest edits and someone with "the power" edits it themselves before my suggestions are acted upon.

Comment: @Bridge - Edits are locked until approved/rejected. If you suggest an edit and someone with enough rep "improves" it, they can mark your suggestion as helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in the first code block is that you're trying to cast a nullable DateTime value to DateTime.

Try casting it to nullable DateTime (`DateTime?`) instead:

```
ValidationDate = (DateTime?)myOtherClass.ValidationDate
```

because you're trying to populate a nullable DateTime field after all.

If you're trying to provide a default value in case `myOtherClass.ValidationDate` is null, then use the coalescing operator (no casts needed):

```
ValidationDate = myOtherClass.ValidationDate ?? DateTime.Now
```

Comment: Both both fields _are_ `DateTime?`. How does this help with the conditional statement that has the problem?

Comment: @Oded thanks for pointing that out; I didn't see the `DateTime.Now` in the second code block

Answer (score 0):

Cast the `null` to a `DateTime?`:

```
ValidationDate = (myOtherClass.VALIDATION_DATE == null) ? 
                                                  (DateTime?)null : DateTime.Now;
```

The conditional operator requires that the two result branches are of the same type or types that can be implicitly convertible.

Since `null` by itself doesn't correspond to any type, you need to cast that branch - the above works because there is an implicit conversion between `DateTime` and `DateTime?` for the `DateTime.Now` branch.

Answer (score 0):

The null coalescing operator is actually `??` which doesn't appear anywhere in your code - what you've used is the Ternary Operator. I believe in order for that to work, the two possible outcomes (in this case `null` and `DateTime.Now`) need to be convertable to the same type (which they're not).

Try changing the line to simply:

```
ValidationDate = myOtherClass.VALIDATION_DATE ?? DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: Or as w0lf points out, make them the same type by casting to nullable datetime.

Answer (score 0):

If ValidationDate in MyOtherClass is a nullable DateTime, and ValidationDate in MyClass is a DateTime (not-nullable), then you can do this:

```
ValidationDate = myOtherClass.ValidationDate?? DateTime.Now
```